# Calling onreadystatechange callback function with parameter in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I found a question on this in SOF ..but didnt find the solution..

this is my code..

```
 if (mefofftasksxmlhttp!=null)
        {
            mefofftasksxmlhttp.onreadystatechange=sasi_ready(taskId);
            mefofftasksxmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
            mefofftasksxmlhttp.send(null);
        }
```

**callback function**

```
function sasi_ready(tskId)
        {
            if (mefofftasksxmlhttp.readyState==4)
            {
               if (mefofftasksxmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    alert('Task Moved to completed Tasks');
                    $('#'+tskId).hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Problem retrieving XML data");
                }
            }
        }
```

this code is doesnt allowing me into the callback when i pass a parameter in the callback function ..but when i remove parameter..thats working fine..

where i went wrong?

Comment: hi sasi can u explain clearly

Comment: `=sasi_ready(taskId);` ? You need to attach a function, not call a function (unless it's a function that returns a function, which sasi_ready doesn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Beetroot-Beetroot already said: You need to pass a function reference to onreadystatechange. If you want to pass a parameter, you could still call a function with this parameter as long as this function will return a function reference

```
function sasi_ready(tskId) {
   return function() {
        if (mefofftasksxmlhttp.readyState==4)
        {
           if (mefofftasksxmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                alert('Task Moved to completed Tasks');
                $('#'+tskId).hide();
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Problem retrieving XML data");
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have, charater for character, the same code sitting in my editor, ready to post. But no need now @devnull69 .